# Is there a way to make vscode automatically write delete[] whenever I declare new?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm relatively new to cpp, and I'm wondering if there's anyway to have visual studio code automatically write `delete[]` a line below whenever I type `new`, kinda similar to how it auto completes parentheses.

I think this would be very helpful for me as I have been learning about the heap and avoiding memory leaks.

Comment: No.  The way to solve the problem is to use types that do this for you like `std::vector`, `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: You should learn about RAII, containers and smart pointers  next. You'll find that you hardly ever need (nor should you) to write new or delete in the first place.

Comment: What would be the use case for this? Typically, when the lifetime of variable is limited by the scope they are in (when the behavior, that you are describing, would be useful) - you don't need `new` at all.

Comment: Handy reading: [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

Comment: That's not as helpful as you think – the most common use case (I'd guess around 99.9%) is to `delete` in a completely different part of the code. You should learn how to do without `new` and `delete` (it's quite rare to see those words at all these days).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about Visual Studio in particular, but this is probably unlikely for a few reasons:

1. What if you call `new` in one function and `delete` in a completely different one? (think constructor/destructor).
2. What if you call `new` but pass ownership to another object, so *they're* then expected to `delete`?
3. What if you call `new` on a bunch of different lines, but only have one `delete` that's in a loop?

If you want to make sure that each `new` has a matching `delete` however, I'd suggest using tools like [CppCheck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cppcheck) (to which I have no affiliation) on your code periodically (ie whenever you push new changes).

Or even better, use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) or one of the many C++ containers like `std::vector` so you don't need to worry about this.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been learning about the heap and avoiding memory leaks.

```
void foo();

void test()
{
    int* p = new int(24);
    foo();
    delete p;
}
```

Question: is the above code leak free?

Answer: **No!!** And whoever or whatever is teaching you that to avoid memory leaks you need to use `delete` is teaching you very very bad C++ programming. The above code will leak if `foo()` throws.

The only solution is to use [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) whenever you need to manage ownership of resources (like you do when you allocate memory). For this use smart pointers or higher abstractions like containers (`std::vector` etc).

So since almost always `new`/`delete` in user code is a bug there aren't tools to help you write `new`/`delete`.